# Why is there a number showing up at the end of the list

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

Here's the code i've written to find a path b/w two nodes.
the o/p contains a number.How can i get rid of it

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,d).
edge(a,e).
edge(e,c).
path(D,D,[D|L]).
path(S,D,[S|L]):-edge(S,X),path(X,D,L).
```

o/p:

Warning: e:/prolog_programs/dfs.pl:6: Singleton variables: [L]

```
?- path(a,d,X).
X = [a, b, c, d|_978] .
```

Comment: That's not a number, it's an unbound variable.

Comment: Try this: `path(D,D,[D]).`.

Comment: The hint was `Singleton variables: [L]`.

Comment: `path(D,D,[D|L]).` This says that `L` can be anything since it's singleton. In Prolog, it uses an anonymous variable to indicate it, `_978` in this case. It's actually a variable, not a number, since it starts with `_`.